# Bind callback to the object instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, callback

I'd like to bind a class method to the object instance so that when the method is invoke as callback it can still access the object instance. I am using an event emitter to generate and fire events.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pyee import EventEmitter

class Component(object):
  _emiter = EventEmitter()

  def emit(self, event_type, event):
    Component._emiter.emit(event_type, event)

def listen_on(event):
  def listen_on_decorator(func):
    print("set event")
    Component._emiter.on(event, func)
    def method_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return method_wrapper
  return listen_on_decorator

class TestComponent(Component):

  @listen_on('test')
  def on_test(self, event):
    print("self is " + str(self))
    print("FF" + str(event))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  t = TestComponent()
  t.emit('test', { 'a': 'dfdsf' })
```

If you run this code, an error is thrown :

```
  File "component.py", line 29, in <module>                                                                                                                                                         [0/1889]
    t.emit('test', { 'a': 'dfdsf' })
  File "component.py", line 8, in emit
    Component._emiter.emit('test', event)
  File "/Users/giuseppe/.virtualenvs/Forex/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyee/__init__.py", line 117, in emit
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "component.py", line 14, in method_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

This is caused by the missing self when the method `on_test` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OP's extra requierements presented on the comments to the other answer, there is this alternative approach.

Here, the decorator is used only to mark which methods will work as emitters - and the actual registry of emitters is done only when the class is actually instantiated, based on the methods that were marked.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pyee import EventEmitter

class Component(object):
    _emiter = EventEmitter()
    def __init__(self):
        for attr_name in dir(self):
            method = getattr(self, attr_name)
            if hasattr(method, "_component_emitter_on"):
                for event in method._component_emitter_on:
                    self._emiter.on(event, method)
            self.attr_name = method

    def emit(self, event_type, event):
        Component._emiter.emit(event_type, event)


def listen_on(event):
    def listen_on_decorator(func):
        print("set event")
        func._component_emitter_on = getattr(func, "_component_emitter_on", []) + [event]
        return func
    return listen_on_decorator


class TestComponent(Component):

    @listen_on('test')
    def on_test(self, event):
        print("self is " + str(self))
        print("FF" + str(event))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = TestComponent()
    t.emit('test', { 'a': 'dfdsf' })
```

(Note I had also removed a redundant indirection level on your decorator - if decorators won't replace the callable itself, just make annotations to it (or with it), they don't need to create another callable)

Comment: Great! This is what I need, have you tried to run the code? Are you sure the extra indirection level wasn't necessary? Because I am getting the following error ` TypeError: on_test() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) `

Comment: I didn't run because I don't have pyee - but I found an error above  - I will f ix it soon.

Comment: Fixed it now - it was a hard to get error because they were actually two, one hidding the other - I had a typo, omitting the "_" on my anotattion attribute - and did forget to remove the call to event registering in the decorator. (It is only done at instantiation)

Comment: I see, I've fixed in a similar way.. the only thing I don't understand is this line ` self.attr_name = method `  why do  you need to set attr_name to the original value?

Comment: whenever one retrieves  a method from an instance in Python, Python creates a _new_  method instance - which points to the function as declared  in the class body.   When I do `self.attr_name = method` in the instance, I override this retrieval mechanism for that instance - the method is now an attribute of that instance. (You may inspect the instance's `__dict__` to check it). Thus, this ensures the `instance.on_test` seen is the one actually decorated as being the event receiver.

Comment: It does not make much of a difference in this case, but would if you were actually decorating the method, with code to be run before and after the actual call, and you would call the method by other ways than dispatching events.

Answer (score 1):

The instance-bound method does not exist, as it is hard to imagine otherwise, at the time the class body is parsed  - which is when decorators are applied.

That means your `on_test` method behaves just like a function, not being "aware" of it's class or instance at that point. When a method is retrieved from an object instance, Python does create an special callable (with "method" type) that essentially will insert the `self` parameter in a call to the original function.

One way to make it work is to decorate this callable (the bound method itself) instead of the raw function. Of course, it only exists at the time the class is instantiated.

Fortunately, in Python, [decorators are mostly a syntactic shortcut to a function call passing the decorated function as a parameter](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#id66) - so you can just rewrite your `TestComponent` class more or less like this:

```
class TestComponent(Component):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
      super().__init__(*args, **kw)
      self.on_test = listen_on('test')(self.on_test)

  def on_test(self, event):
    print("self is " + str(self))
    print("FF" + str(event))
```

Note that as we re-assign the `self.on_test` instance member after decoration, it ceases to behave as a method when called through the instance - it will be a mere function call, without magic inserting of `self` - however, the `self` parameter is already bound to that callable on the moment `self.on_test` is retrieved and passed as a parameter to the decorator, on the right side of that line.

** alternative **
The comments suggests the above use does not look like the decorator is used - one can rewrite that to actually use the decorator syntax, just doing this - although this will hide the method from static code checkers, such as IDE autocompletion engines, and linters:

```
class TestComponent(Component):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
      super().__init__(*args, **kw)

      @listen_on('test')
      def on_test(self, event):
          print("self is " + str(self))
          print("FF" + str(event))

      self.on_test = on_test
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. But this solution doesn't use decorator. I don't want to do this : `self.on_test = listen_on('test')(self.on_test) ` in the constructor.

Comment: Yes - it i does use the decorator - that call is exacetly what the decorator does internally,

Comment: Yes, Sorry I didn't express myself correctly. I'd like to keep the @listen_on syntax. I don't like adding a line to the constructor to register the listener methods.. It is not self-describing. If I go for that solution, I don't need the decorator at all. Instead what I am trying to do is to hide the emitter logic from the inherited class.

Comment: still that's not what I want to do.. because the on_test method is not part of the interface of the class TestComponent when it should be.

Comment: Registerng the listener methods on the constructor is one thing you will have to live with - using decorators or not - the instance only exists after it is created.

You can have however a baseclass that will register the emiter logic for each instance in all decorated methods on the subclasses - that still would be done on `__init__`, is one order of magnitude more complex, but only on the base class `__init__`

Comment: ``You can have however a baseclass that will register the emiter logic for each instance in all decorated methods on the subclasses`` that's exactly what I need. Hide the registration logic in the base class

Comment: How can I get the list of  decorated methods in the constructor of the base class? because if I have that I can register them

Comment: I made that ina  separate answer